Nested switch se salta lineas
Estoy iniciando mi aprendizaje de Java y estoy tratando de crear un proyecto basico de reservas en linea. Cree un switch para que el usuario elija el tipo de habitacion y dentro de ese switch cree otro para que elija el metodo de pago y asi dar diferentes tarifas acorde al metodo (Ya trate con if/else y funciono, pero queria hacerlo con switch para mejor interaccion)
El problema es que al cumplir con el segundo switch, no se detiene, si no que pasa a la case 2 del primer switch
Dejo el codigo aca:
 sytem.out.println("Seleccione el tipo de habitacion: ");
 System.out.println("Habitacion 1: Junior Suite Vista al Jardin (Max 2pax)- $247.95 por    
 noche");
 System.out.println("Habitacion 2: Suite Deluxe Vista al Mar (Max 4pax) - $585.60 por 
 noche");
 System.out.println("Elija el tipo de Habitacion que desea: ");
 int Habitacion = teclado.nextInt();
    
 int metodo_pago;
 double Hab1 = 247.95; 
 double Hab2 = 585.60;
 double total;
 double Impuesto = 0.13;
    

 switch (Habitacion) {
    case 1: // Habitacion Junior Suite Vista al Jardin 2pax
     System.out.println("Habitacion Junior Suite Vista al jardin");
     System.out.println("Indique su metodo de pago 1.Efectivo o 2.Tarjeta*: ");
     System.out.println("* Al pagar con su tarjeta se le descuenta el IVA");
     metodo_pago = teclado.nextInt();

     System.out.println("Reserva Exitosa! Por favor revise los datos a continuacion:");

     System.out.println("Tipo de habitacion Junior Suite Vista al jardin");
     System.out.println("Nombre de la reserva " + nombre);
     System.out.println("Total de huespedes: " + personas);
     System.out.println("Total de noches de estadia:  " + noches);
     System.out.println("Las fechas de su visita son del : " + ingreso + " al " + 
     salida);

            switch (metodo_pago) {
                 case 1:

                   total = Hab1 * noches; 
                   System.out.println("El precio total por la(s) " + noches + " 
                   noche(s) de su estadia es de: " + total);
                   break;

                 case 2:

                 total = Hab1 * noches - (Hab1 * Impuesto) * noches; 

                 System.out.println("El precio total por la(s)" + noches + " noches(s) 
                 de su estadia es de: " + total);
                 break;
               
                 default: System.out.println("El valor ingresado no corresponde a una 
                 de las opciones"); 
                    break;

            }
         

    case 2: // Habitacion Suite Deluxe Vista al Mar

     System.out.println("Habitacion Suite Deluxe Vista al Mar");
     System.out.println("Indique su metodo de pago (Efectivo/Tarjeta)*: ");
     System.out.println("* Al pagar con su tarjeta se le descuenta el IVA");
     metodo_pago = teclado.nextInt();

     System.out.println("Reserva Exitosa! Por favor revise los datos a continuacion:");

            
     System.out.println("Tipo de habitacion: Suite Deluxe Vista al Mar");
     System.out.println("Nombre de la reserva " + nombre);
     System.out.println("Total de huespedes: " + personas);
     System.out.println("Total de noches de estadia:  " + noches);
     System.out.println("Las fechas de su visita son del : " + ingreso + " al " + 
     salida);

            switch (metodo_pago) {
                 case 1:

                 total = Hab2 * noches; 
                 System.out.println("El precio total por la(s)" + noches + "(s) de su 
                 estadia es de: " + total);

                 case 2:

                 total = Hab2 * noches- (Hab2 * Impuesto) * noches;
                 System.out.println("El precio total por la(s)" + noches + "(s) de su 
                  estadia es de: " + total);
                 break;  

                 default: System.out.println("El valor ingresado no corresponde a 
                 ninguna de las opciones");
                 break;
            }

De nuevo, el problema es que cuando me da los resultados del segundo switch salta inmediatamente al case 2 del primer switch

El problema es que hay lugares donde necesitas los break; para detener el flujo del switch, por ejemplo, actualmente así es tu código :
 switch (Habitacion) {
    case 1: // Habitacion Junior Suite Vista al Jardin 2pax
          ...
          ...           
            switch (metodo_pago) {
                 case 1:
                   ...
                   ...
                   break;
                 case 2:
                 ...
                 ...
                 break;                   
                 ...
                 ...
                 default: System.out.println("El valor ingresado no corresponde a una de las opciones"); 
                  break;
            }
         
    case 2: // Habitacion Suite Deluxe Vista al Mar
            ...
            ...
            switch (metodo_pago) {
                 case 1:
                 ...
                 ...
                 case 2:
                 ...
                 ...
                 break;  

                 default: System.out.println("El valor ingresado no corresponde a 
                 ninguna de las opciones");
                 break;
            }

En realidad necesitas terminar cada opción case con un break;
realiza el siguiente cambio:
 switch (Habitacion) {
    case 1: // Habitacion Junior Suite Vista al Jardin 2pax
     System.out.println("Habitacion Junior Suite Vista al jardin");
     System.out.println("Indique su metodo de pago 1.Efectivo o 2.Tarjeta*: ");
     System.out.println("* Al pagar con su tarjeta se le descuenta el IVA");
     metodo_pago = teclado.nextInt();

     System.out.println("Reserva Exitosa! Por favor revise los datos a continuacion:");

     System.out.println("Tipo de habitacion Junior Suite Vista al jardin");
     System.out.println("Nombre de la reserva " + nombre);
     System.out.println("Total de huespedes: " + personas);
     System.out.println("Total de noches de estadia:  " + noches);
     System.out.println("Las fechas de su visita son del : " + ingreso + " al " + 
     salida);

            switch (metodo_pago) {
                 case 1:

                   total = Hab1 * noches; 
                   System.out.println("El precio total por la(s) " + noches + " 
                   noche(s) de su estadia es de: " + total);
                   break;

                 case 2:

                 total = Hab1 * noches - (Hab1 * Impuesto) * noches; 

                 System.out.println("El precio total por la(s)" + noches + " noches(s) 
                 de su estadia es de: " + total);
                 break;

                 default: System.out.println("El valor ingresado no corresponde a una 
                 de las opciones"); 
                    break;

            }
              break; //* Se agrega break!  
           
    case 2: // Habitacion Suite Deluxe Vista al Mar

     System.out.println("Habitacion Suite Deluxe Vista al Mar");
     System.out.println("Indique su metodo de pago (Efectivo/Tarjeta)*: ");
     System.out.println("* Al pagar con su tarjeta se le descuenta el IVA");
     metodo_pago = teclado.nextInt();

     System.out.println("Reserva Exitosa! Por favor revise los datos a continuacion:");


     System.out.println("Tipo de habitacion: Suite Deluxe Vista al Mar");
     System.out.println("Nombre de la reserva " + nombre);
     System.out.println("Total de huespedes: " + personas);
     System.out.println("Total de noches de estadia:  " + noches);
     System.out.println("Las fechas de su visita son del : " + ingreso + " al " + 
     salida);

            switch (metodo_pago) {
                 case 1:

                 total = Hab2 * noches; 
                 System.out.println("El precio total por la(s)" + noches + "(s) de su 
                 estadia es de: " + total);
                  break; //* Agrega break
                 case 2:

                 total = Hab2 * noches- (Hab2 * Impuesto) * noches;
                 System.out.println("El precio total por la(s)" + noches + "(s) de su 
                  estadia es de: " + total);
                 break;  

                 default: System.out.println("El valor ingresado no corresponde a 
                 ninguna de las opciones");
                 break;
            }

         break; //* Agrega break 

        default: //* Agrega default y break 
          System.out.println("Opción de habitación no válida");
        break;
}

